# Creating an auction model a la eBay max bid style

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to work with a few concepts of auction house style models, right now I have an `Auction` model and a `Bid` model.  The two relate through a ForeignKey in the `Bid` model, with `Bid.amount` containing the amount that a user has bid.

I already utilise the ordering on the `Bid.amount` field to define the highest bid, but I was wondering if there is a simple way to define a `max_bid` and the output to the user is what looks like a "smart bidding" system, a la eBay.

So say if the following applies

```
$ bid1 = 9000  # max bid for bid1 object
$ bid2 = 6000  # max bid for bid2 object
$ bid3 = 9500  # max bid for bid3 object
$ starting_price = 5000  # starting price for the auction
```

When bid1 is placed (indicating that the highest the smart bid should go up to is 9000) the current auction price should remain at 5000, as there are no other bids on the item.

When bid2 is placed, the current auction price should then increase to 6001 (as bid1 is still higher)

When bid3 is placed, the current auction price should then increase to 9001 (outbidding bid1, and becoming the current highest bidder).

if anyone has any ideas of the best way to tackle this, I'd love to hear them.

Edit: my models, for reference

```
class Auction(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User)
    item_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    winner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Auction_Winner', blank=True, null=True)
    reserve = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    is_guildbank_sale = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, null=True)
    expires = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, null=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s selling %s' % (self.seller, self.item_name)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''
        if not self.id:
            self.created = datetime.today()
        self.expires = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=3)
        return super(Auction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Bid(models.Model):
    auction = models.ForeignKey(Auction, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='bid_owner', null=True)
    bid_amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Auction Bid"
        verbose_name_plural = "Auction Bids"
        ordering = ['-bid_amount',]
        get_latest_by = 'bid_amount'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a function for your Auction model and make it an instance attribute with the @property decorator. I would not store it as a databased value because you will be running into race condition issues.

```
class Auction(models.Model):
    ...
    def _get_increment(self):
        """ add some logic to base incrementing amount on starting price """
        ...

    @property
    def current_auction_price(self):
        price = self.starting_amount
        bid_increment = self._get_increment()

        """ If there is more than 1 bid present, take the second highest value and add the bid increment. """
        if self.bid_set.count() > 1:
            price = self.bid_set.order_by('bid_amount')[-2].bid_amount + bid_increment

        return price
```

This will allow you to use the value directly in a template.

```
{{ object.current_auction_price }}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I see a few errors you might wish to correct in your code however. firstly, you can't have a negative index so to get the second highest bid would be [1] not [-2]. secondly there is no attribute for bid_set named order, I believe what you were looking for would have been .order_by.  Seeing as this is already defined in the class Meta, wouldn't this just need to be .all()?

Comment: Yes, negative indexes are valid. [link](www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html).  My mistake was sorting descending and still taking from the end.  I changed my sort to ascending and fixed the order_by method name.

Comment: Perfect, that explains why I was getting negative index errors. Thanks for clearing that up. :)

Comment: And I missed you Meta class ordering, so you don't need to re-sort like I did.

Comment: @VictorBruno is there source code for this example in a working django project on github?